Trace of Operators
Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be two Hilbert Spaces. Let A be an bounded linear operator between $H_1$ and $H_2$ such that $AA^*$ is traceclass, where $A^*$ denotes the adjoint Operator.
Is it true that we have for the trace:
$$
Tr(A^*A)=Tr(AA^*) ?
$$

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Show your work. The Parseval identity may help.

Let $\{e_j\}$ be an ONB of $H_2$ and $\{f_i\}$ be an ONB of $H_1$, then,
$$\begin{split}
\text{Tr}(AA^\ast) &= \sum_j \langle e_j, AA^\ast e_j\rangle\\
&= \sum_j \|A^\ast e_j\|^2\\
&= \sum_j \sum_i |\langle f_i, A^\ast e_j\rangle |^2\\
&= \sum_i \sum_j |\langle Af_i, e_j\rangle |^2\\
&= \sum_i \|Af_i\|^2\\
&= \sum_i \langle f_i, A^\ast Af_i\rangle\\
&= \text{Tr}(A^\ast A)
\end{split}$$
